# how to expose postgres hosted in EKS and connect to postgres using PG admin or DBeaver non SSL

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-load-balancer-controller

> in kubernetes i have postgres as a stateful set and i have it defined as service postgres then i want to expose it as an ingress.
> i have changed type from clusterip to NodePort of the service and i have created ingress for postgres like below

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: postgres
  namespace: postgres

  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: eks-dev-test-postgres-group
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":5432}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: eks-dev-test-alb-postgres
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=dev-test,Team=devops


spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - host: postgres.test.XXXXXX.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: postgres
                port:
                  number: 5432
```

> i use alb ingress controller to create/manage  ingress

> here in AWS, i have created new load balancer name : eks-dev-test-alb-postgres
> region : us-east-1
> load balancer arn: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:XXXXX:loadbalancer/app/eks-dev-test-alb-postgres/XXXXX
> and security group inbound rules updated to 5432 opens to everyone
> this vpc is secured by aws vpn and i`m connected to vpn

> i turned off ssl in pgadmin and attached the snip of error

> in DB weaver, when i`m trying to TEST CONNECTION in universal database management tool (DBeaver) i`m facing "An error occurred while setting up the SSL connection".

[image]

ANSWER:

> Service type should be : LoadBalancer

> in service annotations : nlb and internal should add like below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-postgresql-external
  labels:
    app: postgresql
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: postgresql
    port: 5432
    targetPort: postgresql
  selector:
    app: postgresql
    release: "postgres"
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - "172.16.0.0/16"
```

---

REF link: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.5/guide/service/nlb/

> Network Load Balancer (NLB) doesnt have SG.

> In EC2 Instance Security Group need to open as 5432

REF link: https://repost.aws/questions/QUuueXAi20QuisbkOhinnbzQ/aws-nlb-security-group

> Check telnet

> then disable SSL in pgamin while creating connection

> Test the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ingress only works for HTTP traffic. You will not able to expose TCP/5432 using ingress.

Consider creating a service of type LoadBalancer with the appropriate annotations by following the AWS Load Balancer Controller documentation:

https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.5/guide/service/nlb/